# Why is node.js faster than python in file reading?

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x

I'm profiling node.js vs python in file (48KB) reading synchronously.

Node.js code

```
var fs = require('fs');
var stime = new Date().getTime() / 1000;

for (var i=0; i<1000; i++){
  var content = fs.readFileSync('npm-debug.log');
}

console.log("Total time took is: " + ((new Date().getTime() / 1000) - stime));
```

Python Code

```
import time
stime = time.time()
for i in range(1000):
    with open('npm-debug.log', mode='r') as infile:
        ax = infile.read();

print("Total time is: " + str(time.time() - stime));
```

Timings are as follows:

```
$ python test.py
Total time is: 0.5195660591125488

$ node test.js
Total time took is: 0.25799989700317383
```

Where is the difference?

1. In File IO or
2. Python list ds allocation

Or Am I not comparing apples to apples?

**EDIT:**

1. Updated python's readlines() to read() for a good comparison
2. Changed the iterations to 1000 from 500

**PURPOSE:**

To understand the truth in node.js is slower than python is slower than C kind of things and if so slow at which place in this context.

Comment: That's not exactly an apples-to-apples comparison.  In node.js, you're calling a function optimized for reading a whole file all at once.  In Python, you're processing the file line by line.  Plus reading the same file over and over again is not testing file i/o at all really since the file will be cached by the OS after the first read.  All, in all, kind of a wonky comparison to draw general conclusions from.

Comment: @jfriend00 Hey your comment made sense. And I tried with infile.read(). Still the overhead is double (0.28 python vs 0.15 node). May be node file reading function is optimized

Comment: The conclusion: the test from the question is NOT "representative" for such comparison

Comment: You're also reading a file so tiny you're measuring something pretty odd. The numbers flip around for me, at least, on a bigger file (16 MB). But either way, such a limited microbenchmark is not going to tell you the 'truth' about which is 'slower'

Comment: Oh, and another thing is that even with `read`, your current code has python defaulting to using an encoding while the node one does not. Long story short, this is not a good benchmark and isn't telling you anything particularly useful.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest what do you think the difference is, for the purposes of the benchmark? The python read is synchronous.

Comment: @pvg, *The python read is synchronous* - it's understood. But Node.js , I suppose, will go slower when dealing with `fs.readFile()` ... comparatively

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest it might but conceptually this measures an identical call (beside the encoding issues) - synchronously read an entire file into memory.

Comment: @pvg, anyway, it seems like `os.open` even more preferable, as @ForceBru have mentioned

Answer (score 7):

`readlines` returns *a list of lines* in the file, so it has to read the data char by char, constantly comparing the current character to any of the newline characters, and keep composing a list of lines.

This is more complicated than simple `file.read()`, which would be the equivalent of what Node.js does.

Also, the length calculated by your Python script is the number of lines, while Node.js gets the number of characters.

---

If you want even more speed, use `os.open` instead of `open`:

```
import os, time


def Test_os(n):
    for x in range(n):
        f = os.open('Speed test.py', os.O_RDONLY)
        data = ""
        t = os.read(f, 1048576).decode('utf8')
        while t:
            data += t
            t = os.read(f, 1048576).decode('utf8')
        os.close(f)

def Test_open(n):
    for x in range(n):
        with open('Speed test.py') as f:
            data = f.read()

s = time.monotonic()
Test_os(500000)
print(time.monotonic() - s)

s = time.monotonic()
Test_open(500000)
print(time.monotonic() - s)
```

On my machine `os.open` is several seconds faster than `open`. The output is as follows:

```
53.68909174999999
58.12600833400029
```

As you can see, `open` is `4.4` seconds slower than `os.open`, although as the number of runs decreases, so does this difference.

Also, you should try tweaking the buffer size of the `os.read` function as different values may give very different timings:

[image: timings]

Here *'operation'* means *a single call to `Test_os`*.

---

If you get rid of bytes' decoding and use `io.BytesIO` instead of mere `bytes` objects, you'll get a considerable speedup:

```
def Test_os(n, buf):
    for x in range(n):
        f = os.open('test.txt', os.O_RDONLY)
        data = io.BytesIO()
        while data.write(os.read(f, buf)):
            ...
        os.close(f)
```

[image: speedup]

Thus, the best result is now `0.038` seconds per call instead of `0.052` (~37% speedup).